# Range partition on CHAR/VARCHAR2 data type for every month

Tags: sql, oracle, partitioning, create-table

We have a table where we are trying to create a RANGE partition on CHAR data type for each month as mentioned below. But we are getting errors.The ACC_DATE value will be like '202010'. Can this be done in ORACLE? because the same can be done in DB2. But we have to implement it in ORACLE.

Error we are getting:

> ORA-14751: Invalid data type for partitioning column of an interval partitioned table

```
CREATE TABLE T_ACCOUNT_PARTITION
(
    V_ACCOUNT_NUM  VARCHAR2(100 CHAR),
    V_ACCOUNT_NAME VARCHAR2(200 CHAR),
    ACC_DATE CHAR(6)
)
PARTITION BY RANGE (ACC_DATE) INTERVAL (NUMTOYMINTERVAL(1, 'MONTH'))
(PARTITION P_MAY2021 VALUES LESS THAN (202105));
```

Comment: I would use DATE datatype for ACC_DATE and store first day of the month. Could be that there is a limitation on datatypes in range partitioning for CHAR datatype.

Comment: We can not change the datatype, as there are other dependencies from vendor team.

Comment: AFAIU, No, you cannot create an interval-partitioned table when the partitioning key is a character.  You can create a range-partitioned table with a partitioning key that has a character data type. In the SQL Language Reference - Restrictions on Interval Partitioning -  you have : "You can specify only one partitioning key column, and it must be of type NUMBER, DATE, FLOAT, or TIMESTAMP. "

Comment: In oracle, an INTERVAL is only applicable to DATE related datatypes. Change the datatype of  ACC_DATE to DATE (which probably makes more sense anyway) and store first day of the month.

Comment: You should **never** store date/time values as strings, use proper `DATE` or `TIMESTAMP` data type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As already mentioned you should never store date or time values as strings, use always proper `DATE` or `TIMESTAMP` data type.

As a workaround you can use VIRTUAL column like this:

```
CREATE TABLE T_ACCOUNT_PARTITION
(
    V_ACCOUNT_NUM  VARCHAR2(100 CHAR),
    V_ACCOUNT_NAME VARCHAR2(200 CHAR),
    ACC_DATE CHAR(6),
    PARTITION_KEY TIMESTAMP(0) GENERATED ALWAYS AS (TO_TIMESTAMP(ACC_DATE, 'YYYYMM')),
    
)
PARTITION BY RANGE (PARTITION_KEY) INTERVAL (NUMTOYMINTERVAL(1, 'MONTH'))
(PARTITION P_MAY2021 VALUES LESS THAN (TIMESTAMP '2021-05-01 00:00:00'));
```